# DocumentBuilder parse path with hashtag

Tags: java, xml, path

I am trying to parse to the Document Builder an xml path which has a hashtag (#) in it, and it does not work, seems that the parser ignores everything that comes after # inclusive. Does anyone know what can I do?

This is the code:

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xml.getAbsolutePath());
```

The xml path looks like this: C:\Users\miruna\e#abc.xml
The error I get: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\miruna\e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say explicitly what is the type of your variable `xml`. But it seems to be

```
File xml = ...;
```

You are using the method [DocumentBuilder.parse(String uri)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String))
which takes an URI string as argument.
In an [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) the `#` has a special meaning,
separating the path from the fragment. Therefore you get the described problem.

To fix it you can either use the method [DocumentBuilder.parse(File f)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.File)) which takes a File as argument.

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xml);
```

or you can stick to the `parse(String uri)` method and fix the conversion from File to URI string

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xml.toURI().toString());
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer. It work with parsing the xml as file. :)

Comment: @MiruOrşa Welcome. If this solved your problem, you should accept the answer.